# Charset on JSON is not showing special characters, getting NULL instead

Tags: php, json, null, character, utf

I'm getting a query result with JSON but with special characters, It's showing NULL instead of the correct result. I've tried `array_map('utf8_encode')` but I'm still getting the same error.

The code:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
   $response["reserves"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();
        array_map('utf8_encode', $product);
        $product["id_reserve"] = $row["id_r"];
        $product["description"] = $row["d_reserve"];
        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["reserves"], $product);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: You must insure that the whole Web application is in the same charset everywhere (DB, HTML,...) or you also can replace the special characters by their value before making your echo - e.g. the word "étrange" would become "\xc3\xa9trange".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The collation in the MySQL database is 'utf8_general_ci' and the header on the PHP is setting charset as UTF8. An echo in PHP is showing the characters right, so I think that's not the problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: an echo BEFORE json_encode() should be ok, but your problem is AFTER that. That is why you get a NULL. Just try out some dummy code with my example, you'll see

Comment: I think I don't understand you...sorry. I try something like this:

$product["description"] = "\xc3\xa9trange". And the output is:

description":"\u00e9trange"

Something is wrong with that then. But I don't what do you want to say with AFTER the json_encode()...

Comment: try to put my code, then to do an echo after json encode :)

Comment: Sorry but I still don't know what code do you say. Do yo mean to take the $row and do and echo after the encode?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86996/discussion-between-user1423168-and-fafanellu).

Comment: Ok. Solved. I'll edit the OP to put the solution.

Comment: I meant : use the special chars BEFOR encode, then encode, and AFTER echo the json var to see what happened. Ok ! Where dit your problem come from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

To set the array value utf-8 the function utf8_encode has to be put before the $row. The result is:

```
$product["description"] = utf8_encode($row["d_reserve"]);
```